# form with a lot of other [probably-empty] entities in the form (Symfony 2.4)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections

I've a problem with the design of a form, I don't know even if the framework allow this...

I have a entity with several values:

```
Contract:
    Id
    Client
    Creation Date
    Comments
    array (Emision)

Emision: 
    Id
    Month
    Year
    Quantity
    Area

Area
    Id
    Name
```

I need create a form for a contract with the emisions for 2 years by area integrated, in other words Area * 24 (1 for month) emisions

That emisions probably doesn't exists, so they shouldn't to be persisted if the field quantity is empty

First of all I tried create an array with emision[area][year][month] in the controller:

```
foreach($areas as $area){
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++){
            $emision = new Emision();
            $emision->setZona($area->getId());
            $emision->setMonth($j);
            $emision->setYear($i);
            $emisiones[$area][$i][$j] = $emision;
        }
    }
```

}

and:

```
return $this->render('ZBPubliBundle:Contrato:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
        'emisiones' => $emisiones
    ));
```

It was easy generate the form in twig with the desired design, but the form had a lot of identic emision object names and I can't get them in the response.

After tried create a lot of new emisions in the contract:

```
$builder
        ->add('Client')
        ->add('createdAt')
        ->add('...')
        ->add('emisiones', 'collection', array('type' => new EmisionContratoType()))
;
```

and

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('cantidad')
        ->add('year', null, array('read_only' => true))
        ->add('month', null, array('read_only' => true))
        ->add('zona', null, array('read_only' => true))
    ;
}
```

and in the controller I've add the emisions directly to the contract object in the controller action but I can't get the emisions for area or year in the view for paint the form...

I'm wondering if there are a 'stylish solution' for my problem...

Tyvm and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Are you saying that the number of related `Emision` entities is going to be variable, and will vary based on what the user inputs?

Comment: No, sorry, the number of emisions will be fixed by:
count(Area) * 2 [years] * 12 [month]
e.g.: Areas = array ('London', 'Lisboa', 'Madrid), so the number will be 72